# How to accelerate Docker container boot time?

Tags: java, docker, containers, war

I am new to containerizing apps using Docker. I could deploy a container including a war file. The war is basically a JAVA web application/servlet that sends back a video file upon receiving the request from end-user. The app deployment using docker was a success and app works fine. However I have some issues regarding its boot time.

From the moment that I create the container by hitting command `docker run -it -d -p 8080:8080 surrogate`, it takes about 5-6 minutes for the container to become operational, meaning that the first 5-6 minute of the container lifetime, it is not responding to end-user requests, and after that it works fine. Is there any way to accelerate this boot time?

Dockerfile includes:

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.72-jre7
ADD surrogate-V1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
WORKDIR "/usr/local/tomcat/"
RUN wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/1r8awydc05ra8wh/a.mp4?dl=1
RUN cp a.mp4\?dl\=1 lego.mp4
```

Comment: Get rid of the `-d` option when running `docker run`. Examine the logs and see what it is trying to do which can take up to 4~5 minutes.

Comment: Your issue could possibly related to this blog post: https://blog.georgovassilis.com/2015/09/13/tomcat-starts-slowly-in-docker-container/

Comment: Thank you Samuel. I just removed -d and it now takes only 8 seconds!!!!!

Comment: Not sure how `-d` resolved your problem. My earlier intention was to make your container not run in background so you could see the logs, which would show you the step that is taking it so long. Btw you use the Dockerfile to build the image, and docker run to turn an image into an instance of the container. Removing stuff from there will only speed up the build step.

Comment: You are right Samuel, That -d did not solve my issue. In fact today I ran the docker command, and it took very long to become responsive to end-user requests. Trying -d, shows that the following step (WAR deployment) is very time taking:       "May 18, 2017 8:07:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/surrogate-V1.war"        I even tried the solution in the link you suggested, it did not work.  Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I did a bit more research and it could be related to the docker storage driver you are using. https://forums.docker.com/t/container-with-mount-is-extremely-slow-and-choking-the-host/11012/6
I'm not sure exactly sure of the problem as I have not used tomcat with docker before. :(

Comment: Thank you Samuel. The problem is solved now.

Comment: care to share your solution?

Comment: Hmm not sure about the last point there about JRE. I think you probably fixed it by downgrading to a lower tomcat version. I think the new 6.0 tomcat image you're sourcing has JRE 7 in it. Anyway, glad you have a easy win there.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

First get rid of -d in the "docker run" command to see what is going on in the background. I noticed the war deployment phase is taking so long (around 15-20 minutes!!!)

The reason in my case was that the tomcat version in the Dockerfile was different from the Tomcat version in the environment from which I exported the web application as WAR. (How to check JRE version: in terminal enter: `JAVA -version`, checking the Tomcat version: from eclipse, when you are exporting, it shows the version).

In my case in Dockerfile, I had :

```
FROM tomcat:7.0.72-jre7
```

I changed it to:

```
FROM tomcat:6.0-jre7
```

It now takes less than 10 seconds!

In a nutshell, make sure that the Tomcat version and JRE versions in the Dockerfile are the same as the environment from which you exported the Java web application as WAR.